# Connecting to SQL Server with PHP: php5.dll missing?

Tags: php, dll

Win 7

I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server with PHP 5.6. I'm using XAMPP and Notepad++. I got the PHP script from offline:

```
<?php
$serverName = "mydatabasename"; 
//serverName\instanceName

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName");
sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
 ?>
```

I have the script saved as a .php . Whenever I turn on my Apache on XAMPP, I get the error

```
"The program can't start because php5.dll is missing from your computer. Try 
reinstalling the program to fix this problem."
```

I googled for the php5.dll and downloaded it, put it in my php/ext. I also read somewhere that I needed phpdbg, but after 5.6 I read that phpdbg is included with PHP. I downloaded the PHP driver SQLSRV32 because to use sqlsrv_* functions a PHP driver is necessary.

When I run test files they all work, except for my connection script.

So, 
1. Why am I getting the "php5.dll" error?
2. Advice for the connection script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use phpinfo() to see where PHP *thinks* the extensions should be / are being called from?
the file you downloaded from google php5.dll was thread-safe version or non thread-safe ? do check with both of them

try  renaming or removing php.ini file ?

Comment: I've been putting the extensions in C:\xampp\php\ext, which I pulled off phpinfo() originally. Phpinfo() also says that Thread Safety is enabled. I don't know if the php5.dll is ts or nts, this is the link where I got it: http://originaldll.com/file/php5.dll/30704.html I copied the download to that php\ext directory

Comment: try renaming your php.ini file

Comment: what do I rename it? or rename it to? It was just "php" so I changed it to "php.ini".

Comment: rename it to php_old.ini then start your web server and check

Comment: the php5.dll error hasn't reappeared! Thank you! I'm still getting an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()" when I try to run the script on localhost. It says the error is on the line with the function "sqlsrv_connect()"

Comment: can u see new php.ini file ?

Comment: Yes. I changed my extensions from nts to ts: extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll  
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll, now the 
fatal error" is gone, the script ran but now I have the "connection cannot be established" error?

Comment: I also changed the line of code beneath the "$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName"); " line to the original line from google search, "$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);" so I could use the if statement correctly

Comment: did u created  database name dbName ? and is mysql server is running on port 3306 ?

Comment: I just found this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/57c230ca-011a-49ab-886c-09fd283a8a93/error-to-connect-mssql-database-through-php?forum=sqldriverforphp I'll try running the script that's not windows auth

Comment: so any success ?